# 301 redirection regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, redirect

I am trying to redirect 301 pages. I came across one issue, in which I am stuck.
1st Page: https://test.example.com/the-magazine/2012-springsummer-issue/about-last-night-event-planning/

For above page i have written the redirect regex as:

```
Source URL: /the-magazine/2012-springsummer-issue/([A-Za-z].*)
Target URL: https://www.example.com/article/$1
```

$1 replaces all the text captured by (.*)

I have another page:

```
2nd Page: https://test.example.com/category/the-magazine/2012-springsummer-issue
```

This page is also being redirect.
How to write a regex to say if '/category/' exists donot redirect to Target URL: https://www.example.com/article/$1

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

expression: `(?<!\/category)\/the-magazine\/2012-springsummer-issue\/([A-Za-z].*)`

- make sure there is no `\category` with a negative lookbehind: `(?<!\/category)`
- match literally: `\/the-magazine\/2012-springsummer-issue\/`
- capture the rest of the url: `([A-Za-z].*)`

---

Example 1:

```
https://test.example.com/the-magazine/2012-springsummer-issue/about-last-night-event-planning
```

Matches `/the-magazine/2012-springsummer-issue/about-last-night-event-planning`, captures  `about-last-night-event-planning`.

Example 2:

```
https://test.example.com/category/the-magazine/2012-springsummer-issue/about-last-night-event-planning
```

Matches nothing, captures nothing